# php.net discourages the use of threaded MPM in production with Apache 2

Tags: apache-2.4, php-fpm, php7, http2, mpm-event

[php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/install.unix.apache2.php) discourages the use of

> threaded MPM in production with Apache 2. Use the prefork MPM, which is the default MPM with Apache 2.0 and 2.2.

It doesn't mention anything about apache 2.4, I have apache 2.4, ubuntu 18.04, php 7.2

I would like to use http\2 which doesnt work with prefork, is still the best practice to use prefork vs event with php fpm and fast cgi?

Comment: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/howto/http2.html#mpm-config